# How do I export a Kotlin JS project?

Tags: kotlin-js

Sorry, but the Kotlin documentation doesn't help me to export a Kotlin JS project to deploy it on my webserver.

I created a new Kotlin Browser Application with the new project wizard in IntelliJ.

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("js") version "1.4.21"
}

group = "com.foo"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    js(LEGACY) {
        browser {
            binaries.executable()
        }
    }
}
```

simple.kt:

```
class APIModule {
    fun greet() = "world"
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Client</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="untitled.js"></script>
<script>
    let module = new untitled.APIModule()
    console.info(`greet: ${module.greet()}`)
</script>


<div id="root"></div>
hallo ralph
</body>
</html>
```

When I call `./gradlew clean browserRun`, it opens a new browser window, and on the JavaScript console, I see the expected `(index):11 greet: world`.

The question now is: What is the right Gradle task to export it. I tried `./gradlew clean browserWebpack`, but when I now open the generated HTML file, I get an `index.html:10 Uncaught TypeError: untitled.APIModule is not a constructor at index.html:10` error.

Answer (score 2):

When using IR compiler with `@JsExport` you can call Kotlin functions from JavaScript.

**`build.gradle.kts`**

```
kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser()
        binaries.executable()
    }
}
```

**`example.kt`** *(in `untitled` project module)*

```kotlin
@JsExport
fun hello() { console.info("hi") }
```

**`index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Client</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="untitled.js"></script>
<script>
    untitled.hello(); // prints "hi" to console.
</script>


<div id="root"></div>
hallo ralph
</body>
</html>
```

Run `./gradlew browserDistribution` then open `build/distributions/index.html`.

---

When using `LEGACY` compiler, I've only been able to invoke Kotlin from JavaScript (for static generated pages) when running the `browserDevelopmentWebpack` Gradle task.

Comment: Possible related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36484